# How to bind a property value while rendering a blazor component in bUnit test case

Tags: unit-testing, blazor, nunit, bunit

I've a StoreTable component in blazor server app where I've placed a condition before rendering few controls

```
public ProductDetailsDto ProductList { get; set; } = new ProductDetailsDto();
public FreightSnpPoliciesDto SnpDTO { get; set; } = new FreightSnpPoliciesDto();


@if (ProductList != null || SnpDTO != null)
{
------
-----Rendering controls here
}
```

Now, in my unit test case I'm trying to find the controls that are placed in condition and they are not getting rendered because I think ProductList and SnpDTO are null.

```
var publishChangesBtn = storeTableComponent.Find("#publishChangesBtn");
```

I need some way to pass these values while rendering. These 2 properties are not [Parameter]

Comment: It's hard to help if you do not share what the properties _are_. Do they come from a service, a cascading value or?

Comment: This section of the bUnit docs are likely to contain your answer: https://bunit.dev/docs/providing-input

Comment: @EgilHansen those properties are populated from a service. I've already mentioned those properties.

Comment: Then the docs have you covered: https://bunit.dev/docs/providing-input/inject-services-into-components. You might also want to watch this talk: https://youtu.be/Co7QetPYiO4